# Stop execution and get user's choice on iPad app

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad, user-interface

I am writing an app with a synchronization feature. And whenever the app finds a conflict between two objects, i want to display something for the user to choose the correct value.

My first idea was to use `UIAlertView` but after i create the alert object and show it, the program continues the execution, and may eventually find other conflicts before the user had time to resolve the first one.

My question here is: is there a better approach on this ? Or is there a way to stop the app and wait for the alert's choice ?

Any links, further reading or suggestions are much appreciated. Thanks for your help and time

Comment: i just found this answer (http://stackoverflow.com/q/1375384/1341626) here on Stack Overflow that might also answer my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how you're setting it up. What you should do is terminate execution of the synchronization when a conflict is found, then start it again from the method called by the alertview.

Comment: that is an even better approach. Thanks

Comment: indeed, not the only way (lots of workarounds), but the way Apple intended this feature to be used.  UPVOTED! :)